# Can't install Windows 10 from Windows 7 PRO

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, grub, windows-10-upgrade, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 7 laptop, a Dell Latitude 3540, with a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I try to upgrade it, and it reboot, I'll select the Windows OS from GRUB, and then the setup fails, because it allow me to login again.

How can I upgrade it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Windows tries to reboot into a recovery state to update, GRUB is jumping in before this. Use the Media Creation Tool to make a 10 disk image and boot from CD or USB.

Comment: will it be free anyway? I heard that only upgraded systems will result as a free one.

Comment: Chose upgrade install when you do it, NOT clean install. Once its booted up it'll self activate within a few minutes.

Comment: oh, cool! so i can run the same upgrade even from boot! thanks ;)

Comment: Actually you can't I am not sure what the author of this answer is suggesting though..

Comment: You upgrade with external media. Create the media(USB/CD), reboot, hit [esc/del/f2/f12] w/e to get bios boot menu and away you go.

Comment: @Linef4ult - Except you can't do an upgrade installation unless you start the installation from within Windows.